# Passing an object fom one component to another witchout parent-child relationship

Tags: angular, typescript

Hi I have simmilar question to [How to pass a value from one component to another component Angular 2 (No parent child relationship)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43136144/how-to-pass-a-value-from-one-component-to-another-component-angular-2-no-parent). I have component1 that subscribe to a service which make .get to the server and take from there an object with few properties. Is this apropriate to transfer this object from component1 to independent component2 which dont have parent-child relationship with that allert method ?

Comment: In component2 I dont whant to subscribe to a service component for observable because it may be expensive operation. Im looking for a possibility to take needed object directly from component1 to component2.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a service to share data between two components that don't have a parent/child relationship. Store the object in the service (triggered by Component1, it sounds like), and then inject the service into Component2 and grab the object from the service.

Comment: And this is a case. In component2 I dont whant to subscribe to a service component for observable because it may be expensive operation. Im looking for a possibility to take needed object directly from component1 to component2.

Comment: Why not have both components subscribed to the same service so they can independently interact with it?

Answer (score 0):

In Angular 1 with emit and broadcast,  we achieve it for more details [visit](http://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/angularjs/understanding-emit-broadcast-and-on-in-angularjs)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Broadcasting</title>
 <script src="lib/angular.js"></script>
 <script>
 var app = angular.module('app', []);
 
 app.controller("firstCtrl", function ($scope) {
 $scope.$on('eventName', function (event, args) {
 $scope.message = args.message;
 console.log($scope.message);
 });
 });
 
 app.controller("secondCtrl", function ($scope) {
 $scope.handleClick = function (msg) {
 $scope.$emit('eventName', { message: msg });
 };
 });
 
 </script>
</head>
<body ng-app="app">
 <div ng-controller="firstCtrl" style="border:2px solid #E75D5C; padding:5px;">
 <h1>Parent Controller</h1>
 <p>Emit Message : </p>
 <br />
 <div ng-controller="secondCtrl" style="border:2px solid #428bca;padding:5px;">
 <h1>Child Controller</h1>
 <input ng-model="msg">
 <button ng-click="handleClick(msg);">Emit</button>
 </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```